# Get New line in Label HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, razorengine

I am saving the text from Textarea. And the text is also stored with new line as well as:

```
   text= "Line1\nLine2"
```

I am getting Data from Database in the above format. But how can I use the new line to show it on screen `<label>@text</label>`

Here is the JSFiddle link for my question:
http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/J8kRw/

I am fetching that data on server side in form like ::

```
 var model = db.GetDossierHeadeRemarks.Select(remarks => new NotesViewModel {
                UserName="RJ",
                Remark=remarks.Remark.Replace("\n","<br/>")
                }).ToList();
```

But in my View page I am showing this form of data as::

```
<label class="RemarkContent">@item.Remark</label>
```

But the Result I am getting is as::

[image]

Comment: You may want to add a process to convert the `\n` into <br> tags before displayed on the frontend. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8kRw/1/)

Comment: @YourFriend  Its not working on my page depends on the more description givenabove into the question.

Comment: Not very well familer with the Razer enging but Give this a try for the output `@Html.Raw(Remark)` or `@Html.Raw(item.Remark)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `@Html.Raw()` helper method.

```
<label class="RemarkContent">@Html.Raw(item.Remark)</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

For showing text with line breaks in a textarea: you could use the `&#10;`

For showing text with line breaks in some html element: use the replace method (every language has one for strings) to replace `\n` by `<br />`